# Issue with Jenkins Casc Plugin and Merge Strategy Method: Main jenkins.yaml File Not Readable

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have recently started using the [Jenkins Casc plugi](https://plugins.jenkins.io/configuration-as-code/)n for my Jenkins configuration, and now I'm attempting to implement the [Merge Strategy method](https://github.com/jenkinsci/configuration-as-code-plugin/blob/master/docs/features/mergeStrategy.md) as described in the documentation. However, I am encountering an issue where Jenkins cannot read my main jenkins.yaml file, which is supposed to point to other yaml files.

The content of my main jenkins.yaml file is structured like this:

```
jenkins:
  configurations:
    - configFile: "jenkins-main.yaml"
    - configFile: "credentials.yaml"
    - configFile: "security.yaml"
```

I have confirmed that the other Yaml files mentioned in the main jenkins.yaml exist in the same directory.

I am seeking assistance in finding a working example of using the merge strategy with the Jenkins Casc plugin since my attempts to find useful links through online searches have been unsuccessful.

Any guidance or examples would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this works only for merging yamls content it will not load several files into one (if you need to load files to one then you need to use helm or any templating for yaml and copy files to /var/jenkins_home/casc_configs/ dir or create configmap and mount it as file to that dir if you use kubernetes)

https://github.com/jenkinsci/configuration-as-code-plugin/tree/master#getting-started

/var/jenkins_home/casc_configs/normal.yml

```
jenkins:
  systemMessage: normal
  globalNodeProperties:
    - envVars:
        env:
          - key: VARIABLE2
            value: bar
```

/var/jenkins_home/casc_configs/overwrite.yml

```
jenkins:
  systemMessage: new message from overwrite
```

you will get

```
jenkins:
  systemMessage: new message from overwrite
  globalNodeProperties:
    - envVars:
        env:
          - key: VARIABLE2
            value: bar
```

you need to specify full tree to owerwrite nested keys